# How can I convert decimal to binary values in python?

Tags: python, list, binary, decimal, data-conversion

I'm novice in python and I developed a function which retrieve decimal values when the code function is equal to 1 and converts them to the binary values but the problem is that it returns a empty list while the list contains a values. I have to get a full list

Here is the function:

```
def coil_val_list(s):
    v = []
    r = []
    i = []
    for p in s:
        if p.haslayer('ModbusADUResponse'):
            try:
                if p['ModbusADUResponse'][1].funcCode == 1:
                    # r = reg_val_list_binary(s)
                    r = v.extend(p['ModbusADUResponse'][1].coilStatus)
                    for i in r:
                        if i == 1:
                            v.extend([1,0,0])
                        else:
                            v += [int(bit)
                    for bit in str( bin(i) )[2:].zfill(8)] [::-1]
            except AttributeError:
                pass
    return v
```

Comment: `bin(15)` might help?

Comment: No it doesn't work. neither bin() or encode() work

Comment: Elaborate, what doesn't work?

Comment: I used    v+= bin(p['ModbusADUResponse'][1].coilStatus) and  v+= str(p['ModbusADUResponse'][1].coilStatus).encode() but I got an empty list

Comment: `v += [bin(...)]` as you're adding a list to a list.

Comment: I tested but I got an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach in order to convert a decimal number into binary.

```
binary_number = '0:05b'.format(int(decimal))
```

or if decimal_number not in string then directly do this.

```
binary_number = '0:05b'.format(decimal)
```

`'0:05b'`, zero before colon concatenate zeros for example if there is 5 number of bits then binary of `5 = 01001` but with writing zero before colon gives `1001`. and `05` after the colon describe the number of bits you want.